# CAShapeLayer is not touchable?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I created a `CAShapeLayer` and added it as a subLayer.
Then I overridden the:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

And it get called successfully, but after I move this layer using `CABasicAnimation`.

It's not longer touchable.

The strange thing is that the original empty place of the `CAShapeLayer` is touchable after the animation finishes.

The structure of the view is as follows:

I subclass UIView and add to it the layer, let's name it view X.

Then I take view X and add it to anther view.

Then I animate view X using `CABasicAnimation`

Code:

```
class AIFloatingMenuItem: UIView
{
var image = UIImage()
var color = UIColor.brown
var location:CGPoint?
var fontName:String?
var text:String?

let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()

convenience init(title:String, img:UIImage, bgColor:UIColor)
{
    self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ITEM_SIZE, height: ITEM_SIZE))
    self.image = img
    self.color = bgColor
    self.drawCircle()
    backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

//MARK: - Drawing -
func drawCircle()
{
    rectShape.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5 , y:0.5)
    rectShape.fillColor = color.cgColor
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: ITEM_SIZE/2, y: ITEM_SIZE/2), radius: ITEM_SIZE/2, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    rectShape.path = path.cgPath
    layer.addSublayer(rectShape)
}
}

class AIFloatingMenu: UIView, CAAnimationDelegate
{
var item:AIFloatingMenuItem?


override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    animateItem1()
}


func animateItem1()
{
    item = AIFloatingMenuItem(title: "title", img: UIImage(named : "icon-plus")!, bgColor: .green)
    let itemsInitialPostition = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 300)
    item?.layer.position = itemsInitialPostition
    self.addSubview(item!)
    drawAnimateY(end: CGPoint(x: item!.layer.position.x, y: 300), isEnd: false, item: item!, delay: 0.5)
}

func drawAnimateY(end:CGPoint, isEnd:Bool, item:AIFloatingMenuItem, delay:Double)
{
    let pathAnimation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    pathAnimation.damping = 13
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock
        {

    }
    pathAnimation.delegate = self
    pathAnimation.duration = 1.5
    pathAnimation.fromValue = item.layer.position
    pathAnimation.toValue = end
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    pathAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay
    item.layer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
}
```

I add a view in the storyboard and set it's class to AIFloatingMenu.

Comment: The current state (e.g. position, size) of an animated layer is not reflected by the layer but by its presentation layer. When you set `isRemovedOnCompletion` to `false` this is also applied after the end of the animation. To avoid this set the position of the layer to its end position before you start the animation, and leave `isRemovedOnCompletion` to `true`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259613/hittest-on-calayer-how-do-you-find-which-actual-layer-was-hit for hit-testing animated layers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I overcame this issue by setting the new position at the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my issue by changing the position of the item being animated to the destination location after the item finishes the Animation:

```
func drawAnimateY(end:CGPoint, isEnd:Bool, item:AIFloatingMenuItem, delay:Double)
{
let pathAnimation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position")
pathAnimation.damping = 13
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock
{
    item.layer.position = end// changing the position of item to the destination location
}
pathAnimation.delegate = self
pathAnimation.duration = 1.5
pathAnimation.fromValue = item.layer.position
pathAnimation.toValue = end
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
pathAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay
item.layer.add(pathAnimation, forKey: nil)
CATransaction.commit()
}
```